# SSO between Liferay 5.2 and PHP through CAS

Tags: java, php, single-sign-on, liferay, cas

I'm trying to use [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas) for Single Sign On between [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/) and a PHP webapp.

I installed [JASIG](http://www.jasig.org/) CAS webapp, created a certificate with keytools and configured Liferay through its administrative GUI (Setting>Authentication>CAS tab) as follows:

[image: Liferay CAS configuration]

When I click on "Sign in" in Liferay menu I'm forwarded to the CAS login page (with the "dirty trick" username==password: I did not configure LDAP, as I'm going to explain below) and then I'm redirected to Liferay again, but I'm not logged in: I see the LR login form again. So I guess that is not working.

The PHP web application , on the other hand, seems to work flawlessly.

So my questions are:

1. is there something wrong in my LR
   configuration?
2. is the LDAP
   mandatory? I'd rather have Liferay
   do the master authentication
   provider and signalling to CAS that
   the user is indeed legit, and then
   use CAS to propagate the ticket to
   the other webapp; do I have to
   develop some CAS plugin to make it
   work this way?

Answer (score 1):

1. Maybe. Did you test the CAS first: browse to https://:/cas/login and try password/password.
2. As far as my understanding, LDAP is mandatory in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will look into it as soon as I can borrow some time... moved over to other projects, in the meanwhile. :)